# Navbar li goes to next line upon resize

Tags: html, css, navigation, css-float, margin

I have a navbar on my website, which is made up of a `ul` and some `li`s inside. The last `li`, Log Out, has to be right aligned. The problem is, when the screen is resized too small, it goes to a line below to prevent running into the other `li`s.

Here's the HTML for the navbar:

```
<div class="navbar">
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>

    <?php if ($user->logged_in) { ?>
        <li><a href="page1.php">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="page2.php">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="page3.php">Page 3</a></li>
        <li style="margin-right: 10px; float: right;"><a href="log_out.php">Log Out</a></li>
    <?php } ?>

</ul>
```

and the CSS:

```
/* Navbar */

.navbar {
    background: #DDDDDD;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar ul {
    border: solid 1px #BBBBBB;
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar ul li {
    border: solid transparent;
    border-width: 0 1px 0 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 16px;
}
.navbar ul li:hover {
    background-image: url("../images/patterns/background.png");
    border-color: #369643;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #167F39;
}

.navbar ul li a {
    color: inherit;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jryfd3b2/ what your looking for ?

Comment: It seems to work in jsfiddle but I don't see what you changed.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't too clear but I'm assuming you don't want the "logout" element to go below the other nav elements. The problem is in your css where your setting a "min-width" to your 'navbar ul' element. Therefore when the screen is reduced below that width it is being hidden.

I say hidden because after executing your code the "logout" element doesnt go below other nav elements it is just completely hidden. (Using Safari).
Deleting the 'min-width' fixed that problem for me. Hope it does for you too.

Comment: Hmm, I tried removing the min-width but it didn't seem to change that behavior. I'm using chrome.

Answer (score 0):

It works well in jsfiddle as well as in local browser.. Overflow is already added.

```
/* Navbar */

.navbar {
    background: #DDDDDD;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar ul {
    border: solid 1px #BBBBBB;
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 600px;
   }
```